# react js lodash loop thru and change a field value

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am new at reactjs and lodash. I have an array of objects which each has many field properties. I want to change a name string value if the boolean property is true. I read thru some of the posts here, seem like .map will loop thru the array

```
const updatedList = this.props.oldList.map((record) => record.IsTrue === 1 ? `$({record.name} (Updated)` : record.name)
```

I ran the test and it did not worked at all. Instead of returning list of object with all its properities, I got the following

```
0: "Test1 (Updated)"
1: "Test2"
```

There is not object with field names and values. I was expecting the following

```
[
  {name: "Test1 (Updated)", IsTrue: 1},
  {name: "Test1", IsTrue: 0}
]
```

Any help with lodash is appreciated.

Comment: Along with update name, you need to return other property like below 
 
`const updatedList = this.props.oldList.map((record) => ({...record, name: record.IsTrue === 1 ? \`$({record.name} (Updated)\` : record.name)})`

Comment: that did not work

Comment: What error did you get? Can you share sample input?

Comment: the value was never updated, even thought isTrue === 1

Comment: const updatedList = this.props.oldList.map((record) => {return {...record, name: record.IsTrue === 1 ? `${record.name} (Updated)` : record.name}})

Comment: Check the answer below, I made some mistakes while writing in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread syntax to return the other key and value and update the name-value where `isTrue` is 1.

```js
const input = [{ name: "Test1", IsTrue: 1 }, { name: "Test1", IsTrue: 0 }],
    output = input.map((record) => ({ 
      ...record,
      name: record.IsTrue === 1 ? `${record.name} (Updated)` : record.name
    }));
console.log(output);
```